# What does SDL_PollEvent do?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am reading an introductory book code about SDL and there is sample code like this:

```
void Game::handleEvents()
{
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            m_bRunning = false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that this will look into the event queue and if there is anything, retrieve it and the run it to the switch statement. Before I added this code, the window was displayed but you cannot drag or drop, close, or resize the window. Now that I added this code, I can close the window which was what I expected. What I didn't expect was I am able to drag and drop the window.

I thought this would be a separate event that I would need to include in the switch statement in the future. Why did drag and drop also work? Its the SDL_PollEvent (because I commented the switch statement but left the 'if', I was still able to drag) but why is that? Also, why only drag and drop was automatically functional? Why not resize?

Comment: It should be `while`, not `if`. But yes, on almost every case you have to respond to platform-specific messages (which SDL internally does when it generates event queue) or window system will not update or even ask user's permission to kill application that isn't responding to its signals.

Answer (score 3):

We do not need to handle all events, some SDL will take care of for us. Events related to the window properties will be taken care of automatically. In order to resize a window, you will have to add the flag SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE when creating the window. While SDL will take care of the actual resizing of the window, it might still require some event handling as the surface will have a different size to paint at, it will not automatically resize any images we try to draw in it.

While I have not found an answer in the documentation to *why* SDL_PollEvent behave as you describe above, or if this is behavior is intended, it works slightly different on different systems. At osx it is possible to move the window without the above function, but the X for closing will not be displayed. By adding the function again, the window can be moved, minimized and closed properly.

According to [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent), SDL_PollEvent is meant to do what you describe, look if there are any events and retrieve them.

Answer (score 3):

Events are not happening right now, they have already occurred in the past, you are getting notifications that they did occur in the order they occured.

The frozen window is a side effect of an implementation detail, set appropriate flags to enable/disable window properties and functionality like resizing, fullscreen, etc.

`SDL_PollEvent` calls `SDL_PumpEvents`, removes the first event in the stack and copies it into the pointer given.

`SDL_PumpEvents` calls into the operating system's event processing API and transforms platform events into SDL_Events, pushing them onto the SDL event stack.

Now the reason windows are frozen on some platforms is that, that is how that platform event loop works, unless you "pump" its event loop it will be considered an unresponsive window and the window manager will want to kill it and its process.